# Centering the contents of a view inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

Here's the layout (below). I'm trying to reposition the location of the checkbox; move it to the right of the view. android:gravity and android:layout_gravity seem to have no effect. Any explanation? This LinearLayout is a child of a Relative Layout.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/deviceLinear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/view1" >

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/devices_icon"
                android:id="@+id/devices_img"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/hardware_phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/devices"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.43"
                android:text="@string/devices"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_devices"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.42"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout file shows no gravity being applied to the checkbox either from the LinearLayout nor the CheckBox item. Looks like you might have mistakenly put gravity on ImageView for the phone image.

Comment: I tried it but removed it because it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try using `android:gravity="right"`

Comment: The entire android:gravity library doesn't seem to work properly with the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want the `CheckBox` to be on the right side of the `LinearLayout`.  Since you have given it a `layout_weight` it will always take up some fixed percentage of the width regardless of its size as you can see by that blue bounding box.

Try wrapping the checkbox in another `LinearLayout` that has `android:orientation='horizontal'`.  Give the `0.42` weight to the wrapping `LinearLayout` and then set the `LinearLayout`'s `android:gravity` to be `right`.  That should keep your spacing while moving the checkbox to the far right.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="0.42"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="right" />

    <CheckBox
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You might also want to consider a `RelativeLayout` which enables you to position Views based on where other views are.

Comment: That worked. Why does `android:gravity="center"` work with textviews and images but not with checkboxes?

Comment: `gravity` applies to the items WITHIN the element its on.  So for a Layout it applies to the things in the layout.  `layout_gravity` positions the view within its containing element.  So what I wrote above could have been switched to no `gravity` on the `LinearLayout` and `layout_gravity=right` on the `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving layout_weight="0.42" to your checkbox, that means that it will be measured with a width based on the LinearLayout's width. By this approach you will never manage to put it on the right.

The best way to achieve your goal is to use a RelativeLayout. Here is my list item layout with a checkbox on the right. Sorry about the merge tag but it is merged inside a RelativeLayout with

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    style="?muListItemImage60x60" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkIsChecked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_checkbox_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_item_checkbox_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_checkbox_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_checkbox_margin_bottom"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/lblChannelTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkIsChecked"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/channel_item_dummy_title" 
    style="?muListItemTextBig" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/lblChannelSubtitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblChannelTitle"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkIsChecked"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:text="@string/channel_item_dummy_subtitle"
    style="?muListItemTextNormal" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/lblChannelCategory"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
   android:layout_below="@+id/lblChannelSubtitle"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkIsChecked"
   android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
   android:includeFontPadding="false"
   android:paddingLeft="3dp"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
   android:textStyle="italic"
   android:text="@string/channel_item_dummy_category"
   style="?muListItemTextNormal_Inverse" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/lblChannelUpdate"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imgChannelIcon"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:includeFontPadding="false"
   android:paddingTop="3dp"
   android:paddingBottom="3dp"
   android:textStyle="italic"
   android:text="@string/channel_item_dummy_update"
   style="?muListItemTextTiny" />
</merge>
```

As you can see I first place an image with layout_alignParentLeft="true" then the checkbox with layout_alignParentRight="true" and finally I arrange the other components based on those two. From your image I can see that you can use your devices_img as the left component (but you will have to give it a fixed height and maybe some margins in order to became the Layout's height) and your check box as your right.

Keep in mind that in a RelativeLayout with wrap_content as height you cannot use the AlignParentBottom attribute.

Hope this helps...